# Unit testing session variable in controller with spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I am trying to test that a session variable is set up in a method in a controller using a unit test in a Grails controller but it is complaining about setting a readonly property:

```
Cannot set readonly property: session for class: MyController
```

I have something like this:

```
class MyController {
   def settingSession = {
       session.var1 = "hello world!"
   }
}
```

and this would be my test:

```
class MyControllerUnitTest extends ControllerSpec {
    def "My test with sessions"() {
       when:
            controller.settingSession()
       then:
            controller.session.var1 == "hello world!"
    }
}
```

I guest that probably I should write an integration test but I would like to know if there is any possibility of doing this in a unit test.

Comment: The error message mentions admin.common.OauthController but it isn't clear how that figures in to the test you have shown.  Did that admin.common.OauthController related error come from the MyControllerUnitTest test shown above?

Comment: Sorry Jeff, this was part of the source code I didn't realise I was using it. I have already change the example. Sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following test will pass with Grails 2.1.0

A controller:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/MyController.groovy
package demo

class MyController {

    def settingSession() {
        session.band = 'King Crimson'
    }
}
```

A unit test:

```
// test/unit/demo/MyControllerTests.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerTests {

    void testSettingSession() {
        controller.settingSession()

        assert session.band == 'King Crimson'
    }
}
```

If you are using Spock:

```
// test/unit/demo/MyControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.*
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void 'test session'() {
        when:
        controller.settingSession()

        then:
        session.band == 'King Crimson'
    }
}
```

Comment: Those tests are in the Grails 2.1.0 project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sessiontest.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I will try on Monday. By the way, I watched last week your talk about metaprogramming at infoq and I just wanted to congratulate for it.